# Test parameters from the TFS - getting proper number of rows and zero columns.

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tfs

After connecting to the TFS I am able to read correct `ITestUiteBase` and get `ITestCase` which I am interested in.  Problem starts when I try to read parameters:

```
        ITestManagementTeamProject p = GetProject();
        ITestSuiteBase ts = p.TestSuites.Find(3);
        ITestCase tc = ts.TestCases.Where(c=> c.Id == 7).FirstOrDefault().TestCase;
        foreach (DataRow row in tc.DefaultTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row.ItemArray.Length);
        }
```

I know that I have 6 rows and 2 columns there. Only I can get on output is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I cannot access columns because there are none (call to `row[0]` throw exception).  Is there any method I should call before I access a row?  How to get those parameters? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Odd, it works okay for me.  I'm just grabbing an ITestCase using ITestCase tc = testManagementTeamProject.TestCases.Find(501);

Comment: I guess it should work. No idea what the problem is. Getting a proper row count and zero columns is new to me...